# java php javascript rsa

Tags: java, javascript, php, rsa

i'm writing to explain you a problem that i'm trying to resolve in last days. I have to encrypt some data in android using a aes key, send this key (encrypted with a public rsa key) to a server and send these aes encrypted data to the server and decrypt these with the aes key sent previously.
Later on, the person who send these data can access them using a portal which allow him to see these data. These data sent to the client are encrypted with a shared aes key exchanged after has bewn encrypted with the public key (like in android) and data will be decrypted client-side in javascript. 
My problem is that i'm searching a compatible rsa format with PHP, JS and JAVA which i'm not finding.

Comment: Sorry i was writing rapidly, i am confused only in the title, writing all the time encrypt and decrypt it is easy.

Comment: Does http://bestmike007.com/2011/08/secure-data-transmission-between-pure-php-and-javascript-using-rsa/ answer your question?

Comment: thank you, as soon as possible i will try it.